# How to reduce drawcall for object with animation in Unity3D

Tags: animation, dynamic, unity-game-engine, batching

I have a pretty simple scene，but it has about 80 character，each of them has animation(the character can play 5 action(run,walk,stand,dance,hit),every character has only 300 vertex， and all the character share the same material，no lightmaped object，no multipass shaders)，According to the Unity official document，the Unity engine would Dynamic Batching these objects，but my drawcall is about 150,is there a solution to reduce the drawcall？

Comment: Additionally in case if you have multiple cameras then create a separate layer and add as culling mask only in Main Camera (or whichever camera you want to render it) and do unselect in all other cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only **Mesh Renderers** and **Particle Systems** are batched. This means that **skinned meshes**, cloth, trail renderers and other types of rendering components are not batched and i think your character got a skinned mesh renderer so it wont batch.